# Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(ObjectUtils.java:246)

Tags: spring, mongodb, resin

I'm getting this Exception in my program, it looked like a endless loop.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287)
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:120)
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:97)
                        at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletFilterChain.doFilter(ServletFilterChain.java:109)
                        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:150)
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
                        at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
                        at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
                        at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
                        at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
                        at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:289)
                        at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:838)
                        at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1346)
                        at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1302)
                        at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:1286)
                        at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:1194)
                        at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleAcceptTaskImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:993)
                        at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.runThread(ConnectionTask.java:117)
                        at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.run(ConnectionTask.java:93)
                        at com.caucho.network.listen.SocketLinkThreadLauncher.handleTasks(SocketLinkThreadLauncher.java:169)
                        at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketAcceptThread.run(TcpSocketAcceptThread.java:61)
                        at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173)
                        at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118)
                       Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
                        at java.util.Arrays.equals(Arrays.java:2392)
                        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl.equals(WildcardTypeImpl.java:200)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(ObjectUtils.java:246)
                        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.equals(ResolvableType.java:803)
                        at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment.findInChain(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:591)
                        at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment.getReference(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:457)
                        at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getReference(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:247)
                        at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.get(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:226)
                        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1207)
                        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1177)
                        at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveType(GenericTypeResolver.java:262)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.resolveType(TypeDiscoverer.java:140)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.createInfo(TypeDiscoverer.java:97)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.createInfo(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:70)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.isResolvedCompletely(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:207)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentINFO : com.cat.controller.avtivity.ActivityController - log-timeactInfo0319 002:25749
TypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
[15-03-30 14:36:28.030] at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.hashCode(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:183)
                        at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:330)
                        at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:98)
```

Why do I got it? Can anyone help me?